# how to output the date in input щт this format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, input, calendar

I make a calendar, when choosing the firstDay and the lastDay, it outputs the date in this format `15February2023 - 28February2023`, how to make it output in this `15/February/2023 - 28/February/2023`
code

```
methods: {
    thisDate(date) {
      this.date = date.firstDay + ' - ' + date.lastDay;
      date.firstDay = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
      date.lastDay = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
  
      console.log(date.lastDay)
```

is it possible to set such a property or function for input?
or is it better to add a few lines to this function,

Comment: using regex you can add reformat the string the way you want, but how is the original date string `15February2023` being generated in the first place?  can the output not be changed on that end instead?  what is your calendar code?

Comment: like `okBtn() { "selectedDate", { firstDay: this.firstDay + this.currentMonthInName + this.currentYear , lastDay: this.lastDay + this.currentMonthInName + this.currentYear, }, `

Comment: longer code snippets are more easily readable when added to the question instead of in a comment, but I appreciate the code nonetheless... Why don't you add `+ "/" +`  between the day and month, and month and year?

Comment: `'15February2023'.match(/\D+|\d+/g).join('/')` gives "15/February/2023".

Comment: @yoduh yes, i was made your method. that works - thank you!